# stateHidden" /> display when build is complete

Tags: android, gradle

I am building my app and I get an error when the build completes:

```
stateHidden" />
```

Can anyone tell me what this is and why I am getting it? I'd love to get rid of this if possible. Doesn't seem to impact my build, but I still don't want it.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you press double click on the error?

Comment: do you see this in any of your xml files?

Comment: @diegoveloper nothing happens when you double click.

Comment: @inner_class7 there are a 2 places in my manifest file that have "stateHidden", they are part of `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateHidden"`